# Multiple file upload in asp.net core using ajax on selection

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Am new to asp.net core, I want to upload multiple files on user file selection with ajax in asp.net core. I use razor page with input file tag.

I follow each step of this article https://codepedia.info/ajax-file-upload-aspnet-core-razor-pages

I am able to call file selection event, but jquery ajax function not getting call, no debug on server side code hence no file upload. not single file upload. my code is not go in debug mode.

CODE

```
   $("#fileUpload").on('change', function () {

                var files = $('#fileUpload').prop("files");                
                var url = "/Index?handler=MyUploader";
                formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("MyUploader", files);              
               
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    success: function (repo) {
                        if (repo.status == "success") {
                            alert("File : " + repo.filename + " is uploaded successfully");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (data) {

                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            });
```

[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmiaw.jpg)

```
 public IActionResult OnPostMyUploader(IFormFile MyUploader)
        {
            if (MyUploader != null)
            {
                string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "mediaUpload");
                string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, MyUploader.FileName);
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    MyUploader.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
                return new ObjectResult(new { status = "success" });
            }
            return new ObjectResult(new { status = "fail" });
    
        }
```

[image: Formdata in browser console]

Comment: your function gets called and the returned code 400 means something wrong with the request data. You should update the question with your page handler `MyUploader` detail.

Comment: ok hopeless adding my other code

Comment: this kind of error can have its detail reported fairly well in the debugging console (the `Output` window). You should have a look in that window first. I doubt that the `XSRF-TOKEN` is not the right header for your antiforgery token. As in my recent project, I use `RequestVerificationToken` instead. Looks like it changes through different versions of asp.net core

Comment: @sabsudo Did you set  `services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");` in `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: am using aspnet core 3.1 version, you want me to use RequestVerificationToken instead of XSRF-TOKEN

Comment: if you want to use custom header name for antiforgery token, you need to configure it (as mj1313 pointed out above), but it has a default name `RequestVerificationToken` as in my case (don't need to configure anything - confirmed in asp.net core 2.2).

Comment: @mj1313 yes I added inside startup.cs I follow this https://codepedia.info/ajax-file-upload-aspnet-core-razor-pages

Comment: have you tried looking in the Output window for the error detail (as I mentioned before)? It would provide more info to help diagnose the issue (maybe you can even solve it yourself)

Comment: @Hopeless after above image error, page not go to debug mode in VS 2019, output window last display message  Starting IIS Express ...
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:35993/" for site "files" application "/"
Successfully registered URL "https://localhost:55664/" for site "files" application "/"
Registration completed for site "files"
IIS Express is running.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
IIS Express is running.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Comment: well, it looks like it's not in the development mode. Make sure that the project configuration mode is `Debug` (not `Release`). I'm pretty sure that such an error should be logged in the Output window. If it's not, your environment has something wrong. The Output window helps us a lot in debugging.

Comment: @sabsudo Can you show us the formdata in the request, you can see it in the f12 network tab.

Comment: @Hopeless its in debug mode only.

Comment: @mj1313 : formdata console log added

Comment: @sabsudo Did you add @Html.AntiForgeryToken() to your current page?

Comment: @mj1313: Thank you so much, adding @Html.AntiForgeryToken() fixed the issue, now everything works perfect as given in this article https://codepedia.info/ajax-file-upload-aspnet-core-razor-pages my bad I missed that part. Also instead of IFormFile I used List<IFormFile> for multiple upload. Merry Christmas

Comment: Hi @sabsudo I post it as answer, if it is helpful, you can [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), thanks, Merry Christmas:)

Answer (score 1):

The `AntiForgeryToken` is a hidden input auto-generated by a post form tag. At first, I have a form in the page, so I didn't add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` and it also worked. If there is no form in the page, then you should add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in the comments. If you do not have a form tag in your page, for security reasons you need to protect from CSRF attacks, so you need to implement AddAntiforgery in your files.

There are three key things you need to add:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");  //---> this line in Startup.cs class
    ...
}
```

The following beforeSend method inside the ajax call:

```
...
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
       $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
},
...
```

And the following at the top of your razor page:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```